# What package rebrands Ubuntu to Ubuntu Studio?

Tags: 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04, I wanted to use Ubuntu Studio file icons, so I installed some packages, (so I can change file icons in Gnome Tweak Tool)but the boot flash screen now displays Ubuntu Studio, what is the package to remove so it goes back to Ubuntu?

Comment: If you're talking about the `plymouth` screen (a wallpaper like screen that is used to hide system messages on boot, often with dots or swirly logo), no package removal will return your settings as it's just a screen (will be left behind). You just select another plymouth screen to be used

Comment: It is the blue "Ubuntu Studio" to the orange "Ubuntu".

Comment: I don't know what you mean by blue vs orange. A photograph with possible arrow as to what you're asking about may help, but it description reads like you're describing the *boot-splash* display screen of `plymouth` that you see on startup & shutdown.